# Apache APISIX integration with Keycloak for token based API

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, apache-apisix

I need to implement a API gateway in front of my AWS load balancer, so that it can take care of authentication, authorization, monitoring etc. I also need to enable SSO for my services.
While trying to implement Apache APISIX with Keycloak using openid-connect plugin (https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/plugins/openid-connect/) . I am getting an invalid token error everytime.
I have followed steps from official documentation as it is but not able to resolve the issue.

https://www.keycloak.org/2021/12/apisix

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to diagnose the problem, you need to provide context like configuration, logs and screenshots, etc.
2. As far as I know, the blog on the APISIX website has a new document about APISIX integration with Keycloak, [you can check it out](https://apisix.apache.org/blog/2022/07/06/use-keycloak-with-api-gateway-to-secure-apis/).

If you have any news, you can reply here.